# Regular expression to extract a section from the wikipedia page

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse a wikipedia page and need to extract a particular section of the page using regex. In the below data, I just need to extract the data inside {{Infobox...}} section.

```
{{Infobox XC Championships
|Name       = Senior men's race at the 2008 IAAF World Cross Country Championships
|Host city  = [[Edinburgh]], [[Scotland]], [[United Kingdom]] {{flagicon|United Kingdom}}
|Location   = [[Holyrood Park]]
|Nations participating  = 45
}}
2008.&lt;ref name=iaaf_00&gt;
{{ Citation 
| last = 
| publisher = [[IAAF]]
}}
```

So in the above example, i need to extract only

```
Infobox XC Championships
|Name       = Senior men's race at the 2008 IAAF World Cross Country Championships
|Host city  = [[Edinburgh]], [[Scotland]], [[United Kingdom]] {{flagicon|United Kingdom}}
|Location   = [[Holyrood Park]]
|Nations participating  = 45
```

Please note that there might be nested {{ }} characters within {{Infobox...}} section. I don't want to omit that.

Below is my regex:

```
\\{\\{Infobox[^{}]*\\}\\}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Regex is not designed to handle nesting.

Comment: Thanks @Amber . Can you suggest me the best way to do this?

Comment: One way would be to iterate over the string, counting opening braces and stopping when you pass an equal number of closing braces.

Comment: Actually I have around 45GB dump and I suppose a lot of time will be spent in processing if I will proceed through this brute force method.  This is the reason I was looking for regex so that it can be a bit faster.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, regexes will almost never solve your problems.  Regexes are an easy, convenient way to solve certain problems, but are generally notorious for poor performance.

Comment: I think I am okay with it as there is no other feasible way I can think currently.

Comment: Note that "this brute force method" is not actually any different from what a regex is doing, in terms of the amount of data processed...

Comment: Actually i don't know much about regex. I didn't mean to be offensive. I was looking to use regex. Thanks!

Comment: See [mediawiki api: how to get infobox from a wikipedia article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638402/mediawiki-api-how-to-get-infobox-from-a-wikipedia-article), and [Getting the infobox section of wikipedia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312346/getting-the-infobox-section-of-wikipedia).  And on regexes, strictly speaking, this is impossible, see [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the formatting of the infobox-section it actually is possible to use a regular expression for this.
Trick is, that you don't even take care of the nested `{{...}}` elements, as each of them will be in its own line starting with a `|`.

```
{{(Infobox.*\r\n(?:\|.*\r\n)+)}}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uITaeQfcRwdQP_o-)

```
{{           start of the string
  (Infobox   start of the capturing group
  .*\r\n     any characters until a line break appears
  (?:        
    \|       line has to start with a |
    .*\r\n   any characters until a line break appears
  )          
  +          the non-capturing group can occur multiple times
  )          end of capturing group
}}
```

So, within the `Infobox`-section you just match lines beginning with a `|` until `}}` pops up.

You may have to experiment with `\r\n` depending on your platform/language. [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uITaeQfcRwdQP_o-) was fine with `\r\n`, but [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/kH8lX3) would only match on `\n`

Comment: I was not aware that a | has to be there at the start of each line in the infobox section. Thanks a lot. It seems to be working :)

Comment: @Kailash to be honest, I don't know if a `|` **has** to be there, as I don't know the syntax wikipedia uses. But in the example you posted it looked like a part of the pattern to me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex..Follow this algorithm

1>Initialize `counter` to `0`

2>Increment `counter` when you find `{{`

3>Decrement `counter` when you find `}}`

4>Repeat step 2 and 3 until counter is 0