# Detect line breaks in a `char[]`

Tags: java, text, character

I use to employ the following method to detect if a character is a whitespace:

```
Character.isWhiteSpace(char character);
```

Now I need to detect all the variants of **line breaks** (`\n`, `\r`, etc.) for all platforms (Linux, Windows, Mac OSX, etc.). Is there any similar way to detect if a character is a line break? If there is not, how can I detect all the possible variants?

---

**Edit from comments:** As I didn't know that line breaks can be represented by several characters, I add some context to the question.

I'm implementing the `write(char[] buffer, int offset, int length)` method in a `Writer` (see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(char[],%20int,%20int))). In addition to other operations, I need to detect line breaks inside the `buffer`. I'm trying to avoid creating an `String` from the `buffer` to preserve memory, as I've seen that sometimes the `buffer` is too big (several MB).

Is there any way to detect line breaks without creating a `String`?

Comment: check if char is System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: What do you mean by "etc"? And bear in mind that on Windows, the normal separator is `"\r\n"`, so not a single character. What bigger problem are you trying to solve? If you're trying to break a string into lines, consider using `BufferedReader` wrapping a `StringReader` instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet didn't know that a line break could be represented by two characters, thanks for the advice

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne thanks for the suggestion but I was looking for a method to detect a line break character by character

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, System.getProperty("line.separator") does not return a char, and the content can be a sequence (like \r\n).

Comment: @JaviFernández, this should be the way to go. However, you cannot test a line break in Java "character by character" because it is often a sequence. So you need to find the sequence in the String...

Comment: @JonSkeet In summary I'm trying to remove all whitespace repetitions that are not line breaks while writing into a `Writer`. For example, the output for `this    is an\n example` would be `this is an\nexample`. I also make other complex operations.

Comment: @Martin so for example if in Windows I use only `\r` or `\n`, it would not be considered as a line break?

Comment: It definitely sounds like this would be simpler by splitting into lines first, using existing functionality.

Comment: @JonSkeet As I'm implementing a `Writer` my only source is an array of `char`s. What functionalities are you suggesting?

Comment: `input.indexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` would do part of the trick. Windows generates `\r\n`, Unix/Linux `\n`, older MACs `\r`, so you will need to check where your input comes from. When parsing Strings or reading from Files, using the `BufferedReader` normally works fine...

Comment: @JaviFernández, where thes the buffer of char come from? Can you post a sample of that input code?

Comment: @Martin thanks for the suggestion but my input is not an `String`, it's an array of `char`s

Comment: @Martin `public void write(char[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException { ...` (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)

Comment: @JaviFernández: `String myString = new String(buffer);` should do the trick... However, trying to parse something you want to use for a Writer sound suspicious, there might be a much easier way to accomplish what you need...

Comment: @Martin it has to be a `Writer` because it's the only way to use it with a third party library.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, but The writer is where you will send your information, right? So, where does it come from?

Comment: @Martin it comes from an `InputStream` which contains a sequence of bytes from a PDF int the Internet. The third party library parses that PDF and offers the possibility of writing the content of the PDF into a `Writer` instead of return a String. The resulting text contains lots of whitespaces and I wanted to remove them before storing it into a database to save space. Some PDF documents can be very big (hundreds of MB) so if a create a new String from the memory needed would be double. That's why I went for the `Writer` approach.

Comment: OK, so you are willing to pass a custom Writer to the third party library that will "filter" what you need?

Comment: The third party library only extracts the text from the PDF, as the original document is only a sequence of bytes. The Writer is used to store the final text.

Comment: OK, but using the Writer is a problem in the first place as you will have a char array (buffer) that's potentially hundreds of MB big! Try rather to use Streams in both ways... If you can pass a custom OutputStream to the library, you could interfere there, but only if it is buffered... However, what does the third-party library return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61504/discussion-between-martin-and-javi-fernandez).

Comment: "As I'm implementing a Writer" - that comment was the first time we had that piece of context. This is a classic XY question, and a great example of why it's worth including context in your question. I suspect there may well be better approaches... heck, even just dumping to disk and then reading from disk would quite possibly simplify things.

Comment: @JonSkeet as I didn't know about line break sequences I thought this question would be clear enough and the answers would go in a different direction

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my question, I hope is clearer now. PS dumping to disk and reading from disk is not a possibility

Comment: Well somewhat... But you've just added another restriction in comments that isn't in the question...

Comment: @JonSkeet which one?

Comment: "dumping to disk and reading from disk is not a possibility" - no explanation, and no mention in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I really appreciate your comments but excuse me because I don't understand why you need so much information about my project. Isn't the question clear? I was only asking if a line break can be detected from a single character.

Comment: The problem is that the answer to that very specific question isn't necessarily the best answer to your actual task. I realize that it can be very difficult to know how much context to give sometimes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use regex to do the work for you:

```
if (!String.valueOf(character).matches("."))
```

Without the `DOTALL` switch, the dot matches all characters *except* newlines, which according the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) includes:

- A newline (line feed) character (`'\n'`),
- A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character (`"\r\n"`),
- A standalone carriage-return character (`'\r'`),
- A next-line character (`'\u0085'`),
- A line-separator character (`'\u2028'`), or
- A paragraph-separator character (`'\u2029`).

Note that line break *sequences* exist, eg `\r\n`, but you asked about *individual* characters. The regex solution would work with one or two char inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There are no other line break characters? Does this work for Windows too?

Comment: @JaviFernández I dug deeper - there are others. See answer, and a more complete solution

Comment: @Martin the regex approach will work for sequences too eg `"\r\n"`

Comment: As @Martin comments this only will work for characters and not for sequences, but the list of all possible characters for a line break is one of the things I was looking for, thank you!!

Comment: @JaviFernández, depending on what you need to do, there are some answers that might help you out. Try to be more specific, for example: "Parse some input string without knowing where it comes from (as long as it's Unix/Linux/MAC/Windows)", "Tell where a file comes from based on line separators", etc. Telling us your goal rather than just a part of it might help people give more specific answers.

Comment: @Martin as I didn't know about line break sequences I thought this question would be clear enough and the answers would go in a different direction, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Bohemian, the problem would be that for `"\r\n"` you would find two line breaks instead of one, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JaviFernández, it's no inconvenience, just a suggestion to make your question as valuable as possible and to get the best possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I posted in my comments, the line separator is not always a "character", but a sequence of characters, depending on the platform. To be independent it would look like this:

```
public String[] splitLines(String input) {
    return input.split("(\r\n|\r|\n)");
}
```

Based on this answer:

[Match linebreaks - \n or \r\n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056306/match-linebreaks-n-or-r-n)

However, this means regex matching, not char matching... However getting a String out of a buffer should be achievable...

Comment: thank you very much for your answer @Martin, but creating a String for each buffer is one of the things I was trying to avoid. I will have this answer into account if a go for a different approach.

Comment: That's fine... Maybe you need to look where your char buffer comes from... If you will be using it in a writer, it has to be generated somewhere, I would assume it comes from a String... If you look at the String constructor for (`char[]`), it uses a Arraycopy, so it's not so expensive: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28char[]%29. If you need to cover all the cases, you will have to do regex matching rather than character matching...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the OS dependent line separator using

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

This will return a string.

But since your are trying use char, checking whether char is '\n' or 'r' is correct.

```
if(yourChar == '\r' || yourChar == '\n')
```

Comment: So are there only two possible characters for a line break?