# detect new line using C++ boost regex_match

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to remove the first line in a string using regex.

As we know, the line return is OS dependent so I am using `\r\n|\n|\r` as regex.

The only issue is, i cannot get it to work..

```
int findMatchOffset(const std::string & iStr, const boost::regex & iExpression)
{
    boost::smatch aResults;
    if(boost::regex_match(iStr, aResults, iExpression))
    {
        return aResults.position();
    }
    return -1;
}

void removeFirstLine(std::string & ioMessageStr)
{
    boost::regex kNewLine("\r\n|\n|\r", boost::regex_constants::bk_vbar);
    int aIndex = findMatchOffset(ioMessageStr, kNewLine);

    ioMessageStr.erase(0, aIndex + 1);
}
```

Can you spot the error in the code above?

regex_match returns false, why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want `boost::regex_search`. `regex_match` is for the whole string, which presumably is not only `\r\n` or `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: Also, it seems you may use `\R` to match any line break style in Boost

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew somebody do sth with this title then : 'Boost regex not working as expected in my code ' ... -_-

Comment: Good, what do you suggest? What searchwords did you use?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OS independent, new line, detect, regex, boost, c++ .. pretty much like in the title.

Comment: Found almost at once: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20058432/3832970

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew congrats