# Regex for different newlines

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

say I have a text, represented as std::string, which contains several different newline, e.g. \r\n but also just \n or even just \r.

I would like now to unify this by replacing all non \r\n newlines, namely all \r and all \n newlines with \r\n.

A simple boost::replace_all(text, "\n", "\r\n"); doesn't work unfortunatly because that would also replace the \n within the already valid \r\n's.

I think std::regex should be a good way to handle this... but how should I express this in a regex? Here is some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "a\rb\nc\r\nd\n";
    std::regex reg(""); // What to put here?
    text = std::regex_replace(text, reg, "\r\n");
    std::cout << text;
}
```

The text should at the end just be `"aaa\r\nbbb\r\nccc\r\nddd\r\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::regex_replace(text, reg, "\r\n|\r|\n");
```

should match.

More info here:

[Match linebreaks - \n or \r\n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056306/match-linebreaks-n-or-r-n)

Comment: A better pattern is `\r\n?|\n`. Alternatives should be matching in different locations as a best practice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: "Better" by what metric? What does "Alternatives should be matching in different locations" mean?

Comment: Better performance, surely not the looks. It's hard to type on a cellphone. I meant to write: "the best practice is to write alternatives in such a way that they could not match at the same locatIon in the string." That way you get rid of unnecessary backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

To swap "`\n`" with no preceding "`\r`"  you can actually use a look ahead:

```
std::regex_replace("\n\n\n\n\n", std::regex("[^\r](?=\n)"), "$1\r\n");
```

This cannot handle the the last new line of a file, so you would need another operation.

To swap "`\r`" with no following "`\n`" is a bit easier:

```
std::regex_replace(text, std::regex("\r[^\n]"), "\r\n");
```

Note depending on the c++ regexp flavor good chance you can't support look behinds if you're considering it.

Comment: The code can't compile. I wrap the "([^\r])\n" with std::regex(). It can compile, but it can't deal correctly with "\n\n". the code translate "\n\n" into "\r\n\n".

Comment: @HarryLeong 4 years later, and finally someone shouts the king is naked! Thanks, you're right on all counts - makes me wonder who upvotes these answers. I'll amend it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The upvotes indeed made me doubt myself until your confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that in two steps:

1. `\n` -> `\r\n`
2. `\r\r\n` -> `\r\n`

or in one step:

`(?:\r\n|\n|\r)` -> `\r\n`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "a\rb\nc\r\nd\n";
    text = std::regex_replace(text, std::regex("(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)"), "\r\n");
    std::cout << text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak, ie.: `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I use std::regex reg("\\R"); but nothing is replaced in the original string...