# Java regex can't work if have \n character

Tags: java, regex

I have project to detect if editor have write html entities, but when it containt \n it doesnt work? why?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class RegexTest {  
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String text = "asdasdas &lt;h1&gt;Test&lt;/h1&gt;</div>";
      String regex = ".*&lt;[^&lt]+&gt;.*";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
      Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
      System.out.println(m.matches());
   }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056634/2551236

Comment: What are you trying to match here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take `\n` into consideration, you can do this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This takes the escape sequence into consideration.

You can also use `Pattern.MULTILINE`, which matches the regex with **Each Line**. So if you add `^` or `$` in your regex, it matches the **starting and ending of the regex respctively for each new line.**

[This is a link to the Oracle docs which may help you better understand, rather than just application of the code.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm) The More You Know...  :)