# Get string between two strings - first string ends with newline

Tags: regex

I have SQL code like:

```
--START
select * from table;
--END
```

I need to get everything between `--START` and `--END`. What I came up with is

`/--START(?s)(.*)--END/`

or

```
`/--START(\r\n|\r|\n)(?s)(.*)--END/`
```

the first one works fine but adds one empty line before the select. So in the end I get

```
empty line
select * from table;
```

What I need to do is to get rid of this one empty line in the beginning. Would anybody help me how to get there: find everything between `--START + newline` and  '--END'?

I tried [Match linebreaks - \n or \r\n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056306/match-linebreaks-n-or-r-n) but answers there didn't work for me.

Comment: Use `/--START\s*(.*?)\s*--END/`, see https://regex101.com/r/i5e5vp/1. Or a more specific `/--START\n(.*?)\n--END/`. Do you always expect a single line between the two strings?

Comment: To add to Victor's comment, you should use DOT ALL mode in your regex tool, assuming there could be more than one line in between `START` and `END`.

Comment: What is the programming language? Do you need to match multiline blocks? What kind of line endings do you need to support? UNIX, MacOS, Windows or all? Do you need any leading/trailing whitespace in the result?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  language is perl, system is Win and UNIX and I do not need any whitespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you may use a pattern like

```
/--START\s*(.*?)\s*--END/s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZErJX/5). `\s*` will match any 0+ whitespaces, but it won't require line breaks after `--START` and before `--END`.

A bit more specific pattern will be

```
/--START\h*\R\s*(.*?)\h*\R\s*--END/s
```

Or, if the `--START` and `--END` should appear at the start of lines, add anchors and `m` modifier:

```
/^--START\h*\R\s*(.*?)\h*\R\s*--END$/sm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZErJX/3) and [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZErJX/4).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (since `m` modifier is used)
- `--START` - left-hand delimiter
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\R` - a line break
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\R` - a linebreak
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `--END` - the right-hand delimiter
- `$` - end of a line.