# Match all instances of \r\n, except that occurring before the very end of the document

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks, carriage-return, linefeed

Using `preg_replace`, I need to define the regex PATTERN to match all instances of the newline sequence `\r\n` exactly, EXCEPT that occuring at the very end of the text.

`preg_replace(PATTERN,'"\r\n"',$text)`

How do I specify PATTERN in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead for end-of-line:

```
preg_replace('/\r\n(?!$)/','"\r\n"',$text)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GXPCv)

Note that if you don't have a specific requirement to match `\r\n`, you can use `\R`, which will match any newline sequence.

Comment: Oh I see - but in my case, it should strictly be `\r\n` (DOS) and not any other type of newline sequence such as `\n` (Unix)

Comment: @ptrcao ok, ignore the comment about `\R`. See my edit

Comment: Actually, I found the comment about `\R` quite useful and I've made a note of it - you should probably add that remark back into the answer as an aside, which could be useful fact for future readers

Comment: @ptrcao good point. I've added it back. :-)

Comment: Why doesn't entering `\r\n(?!$)` into https://regex101.com/ work to select it?

Comment: @ptrcao I'm not sure how to enter a `\r` character on regex101. I've added a demo on 3v4l instead.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be any different in one regex utility over another - isn't Regex universal?  [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056306/match-linebreaks-n-or-r-n) might be relevant, however

Comment: @ptrcao the flavour of regex is the same but I don't think it's possible to insert a carriage-return character into the test string in regex101. hence the 3v4l demo