# Problem when reading file with non-English characters in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, file, character-encoding

Currently, I'm facing an issue of reading a file that contains non-English characters. I need to read that file line by line using the following code:

```
while(!feof($handle)) {
   $line = fgets($handle);
}
```

The case is this file has 1711 lines, but the strange thing is it shows 1766 lines when I tried traversing that file.

```
$text = file_get_contents($filePath);
$numOfLines = count(explode(PHP_EOL, $text));
```

[image: screenshot of the file]

I would appreciate so much if anyone can help me out this issue.

Comment: 1) Try reducing that file to a smaller one. 2) If you still can't figure out, please share that smaller version in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged 'character-encoding', so at least you know what the start of the problem is. You've got some ... probably ... UTF8 characters in there and I'm betting some are multi-byte wide. You are counting your 'lines' by exploding on the `PHP_EOL` character, which I'm guessing is `0x0A`. Some of your multi-byte-wide characters contain `0x0A` as a single byte of their 'character', so `explode` (acting on bytes and not multi-byte characters) is treating that as the end of a 'line'. `var_dump` your exploded array and you'll see the issue easily enough.

Try `count(mb_split('(\r?\n)', $text))` and see what you get. My regex is poor though and that might not work. I would see this question for more help on the regex you need to split on a new line:

[Match linebreaks - \n or \r\n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056306/match-linebreaks-n-or-r-n)

Remember that your line ending might possibly be `\u0085`, but I doubt it as `PHP_EOL` is being *too* aggressive.

If `mb_split` works, remember that you'll need to be using PHP's `mb_` functions for all of your string manipulations. PHP's standard string functions assume single-byte characters and provide the separate `mb_` functions to handle multi-byte wide characters.