# Notepad++ Selectively delete lines within a file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a dual .srt file that looks like this:

```
1
00:07:14,120 --> 00:07:16,953
[French line]
[Russian line]

2
00:07:16,960 --> 00:07:19,952
[French line]
[Russian line]

3
00:07:21,240 --> 00:07:24,835
[French line]
[Russian line]
```

I would like to delete all the Russian lines (plus the corresponding CRLF's). Which means lines 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, and so on. It's every 5 lines, starting at line 4.

I guess Notepad++'s "Find in files" should be able to do it with the right RegEx (but I'm open to any solution). Could you please help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: is *[Russian line]* a fix text?

Comment: Please include your current regex (how far you got), it's helpful for others to understand the context/data you're processing.

Comment: @bobblebubble 's answer solved it beautifully. Plus the regex101 site seems really useful. Many thanks for that! Problem solved.

Comment: @JoseHidalgo Welcome! I think you could further use [`(?>\R?.+){3}\K\R.+`](https://regex101.com/r/Gq8tS6/1) which can be slightly more efficient, I added it to my answer. Glad it helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To target every nth line in non empty line sequences:

```
(?:(?:\R|\A).+){3}\K\R.+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/z3Gm0Q/2) (explanation on right side)

- `\A` matches [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) of the string
- `\R` matches any [newline sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49791415/5527985)
- `\K` [resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match
- `.+` matches [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (besides newline)
- `(?:` [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) `)` `{3}` [quantified](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) three times

Click on "replace all" and replace with empty.
Make sure to uncheck *[ ] dot matches newline* in the replace dialogue.
A bit more efficient alternative with [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html): [`(?>\R?.+){3}\K\R.+`](https://regex101.com/r/Gq8tS6/1)